# How do I remove Notification from status bar?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am displaying a `Notification` in status bar depending up on my condition. Up to this, it is OK.

Now problem in my application is when I come back to application, still the `Notification` is displayed in the status bar.

I don't want the `Notification` when I come back from the application. For this give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `cancel()` your own `Notifications` via the `NotificationManager`. It is up to you to decide when to `cancel()` it and when to show it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough rep to add comment so @Commonware . . .  it would be more helpful to future readers if you gave more specific details like telling them to use a 
 **"notification id"**  when they create the notification and use that ID to cancel the notification.
If you give an answer make it complete or at least provide the full details. These posts are not only meant for the OP it helps others who come across this post as well.
like so

```
final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService (NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"A New Message!",System.currentTimeMillis());

notification.defaults=Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE+Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AndroidNotifications.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(AndroidNotifications.this, title,message, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Then to cancel it you call

```
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

or you can call

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cancelNotificationInBar() {
        NotificationCreator notification = new NotificationCreator(getApplicationContext());
        notification.mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notification.mNotificationManager != null) {
            notification.mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
        }
    }
```